# ui tabs set started tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-tabs

I have problem with ui tabs. I used it on modal ui. When I first show modal everything is good but when I close modal and reopen it I have problem. I don't know how set index tab to 0 when I reopened it.

I try use select option in event ui tabs, modal but it not work.

My tested codes

```
$("#dialogAdd").dialog({
  height: 'auto',
  width: 'auto',
  modal: true,
  autoOpen: false,
  resizable: false,
  open: function () {
    $('#tab').tabs('select', 0);
  }
});
```

I test tab event show, open , and set   `$('#tab').tabs('select', 0);` but it's not work. I have to set select to 0 index everytime when dialog with tabs was showed

I use JQueryUI 1.8.23

Comment: Which JQueryUI version are you using? v1.9 is slightly different than 1.8.X

Answer (score 0):

You should add this code in the function that opens the tab (and not only when creating it).

```
$("#dialogAdd").tabs("select", 0);
```

Comment: my tab is on dialog (dialogAdd) so when I have to add your code? In event when I open dialog?